# Cómo remplazar una cadena si ésta empieza por un determinado texto

Tags: php, str-replace, preg-match

Tengo este `switch`:

```
switch ($message){
    case preg_math('/link ', $message):
    // remplazar /link  por ''
    $resultado = str_replace('/link ', '', $message)
}
print $resultado
```

El problema es que no me lo recibe. Intento que si `$message` empieza con

> /link

remplazar

> /link

por

> 

y finalmente mostrar el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
creamos una expresion regular:

1. en php se encierra la expresion entre `/ regex /`
2. el operador `^` dice que empiese por, en este caso empiese por
   `^/link`
3. el operador `\s` encuentra los espacios
4. el operado `+` encuentra el elemento precedente 1 o mas veces

**tu codigo:**

```
$message = "/link hola que tal";

switch(true){
  case preg_match('/^\/link\s+/', $message):
    echo "remplazar /link  por ''<br>";
    $resultado = preg_replace('/^\/link\s+/',"", $message );
    echo $resultado;
    break;
}
```

Comment: No me funciona 
el valor de $message
es 
$message = $update['message']['text']

Comment: @murcielago09z Y ¿qué hay dentro de  `$update['message']['text']`? Por favor, añade a tu pregunta el texto que hay en `$message`

Comment: $update['message']['text] devuelve una string
en $message hay muchos objetos